# Remove extra spaces from a python string

Tags: python

I have a string which contains the following information.

```
mystring = "'$1$Not Running', ''"
```

I want to be able to remove the extra space and `, ''` after the Running. I tried to use `strip()` but it does not seem to work.

My desired output is `mystring = "'$2$Not Running'"`

I am not sure what I am missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the general rule? Is always the same characters? Do you want to remove them somewhere else, or only the last 4 characters?

Comment: You could use `split(",")[0]`, but we'd need to see more more possible values in order to generalize it.

Comment: only from the end of the string and they are always the same four characters

Comment: `x = '"{}"'.format(x.strip(", '"))` ?

Comment: If it's always the same 4 characters then https://stackoverflow.com/a/58185942/1011724 is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easier solutions would be to `partition` your string based on the comma:

```
mystring, comma, rest = mystring.partition(",")
```

This solution depends on there not being any commas in the string other than that one.

The better solution would be to figure out *why* the extra characters are in your string and what you can do to avoid it.

If that isn't possible, it looks like the string is valid Python, so you could parse it as a tuple and always pick the first element:

```
import ast
mystring, _ = ast.literal_eval(mystring)
```

Although in this case you would get what's *inside* the single quotes, not the single quotes as characters themselves.

Answer (score 1):

i assume you want to remove the final 4 char's in your string. To do this you can simply

```
mystring = mystring[:-4]
```

if this is not right tell me and ill try to find a solution

Comment: If I want to remove ```, {}```, how would I do that

Answer (score 1):

`strip()` only removes spaces as the beginning and end of a string. Since what you want to remove is in the middle, it won't work for you.

You can use regular expressions to search and replace for specific strings:

```
import re

mystring = "'$1$Not Running', ''"
mynewstring = re.sub(", ''", "", mystring)
print(mynewstring)
# '$1$Not Running'
```

I'm not sure what extra space you're talking about, but you can use similar logic to replace it.

If this is literally the only thing you need it for, then some of the other answers might be simpler. If you need it for several different cases of input, this might be a better option. We'd need to see more examples of input to figure that out though.

Answer (score 0):

If the 4 characters you want to replace are `', '` then you can just use the `string.replace()` function to replace them with an empty string `''`:

```
mystring = mystring.replace( "', '", '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something better but you can try to use split()

```
mynewstring = mystring.split()[0] + mystring.split()[1]
```

Comment: fyi `mystring.rsplit(" ", 1)[0]`. But I doubt this is the way to go in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, much better.